# How to install/use Ruby Shoes (without Hackety Hack)?

Tags: ruby, shoes

**SOLUTION:**
You have the same problem, you have to compile Shoes (https://github.com/shoes/shoes/wiki/Building-Shoes-on-Linux)

if `rake` doesn't work, try to install ruby 1.9.2 through rvm.

---

I recently started to learn Ruby, and i came across this library.

I tried to install it using the .run file provided by the official site, but it seems like it's broken. If i run it, it tells me:

```
./shoes-3.1.0.run: 1: eval: ./shoes: not found
```

And yes, after extracting the file, i found a folder which didnt contain it.
The only runnable thing i find is HacketyHack, which worked, but I prefer to use my own editor.

Since I have just started to learn Ruby, I'm not comfortable with playing with the .rb files to get it working outside of HH. I also tried to install it via apt-get, but after running 'shoes', all i get is:

```
no such file to load -- rubygems
```

Compiling from source code didn't work for me. Is there anything else I can try, or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `ruby -v` and `gem -v` on your system?

Comment: ruby -v: `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]` gem -v: `1.8.15`

Comment: If you have the solution, it's acceptable (and often encouraged) to answer your own question instead of editing it. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be your ruby version. `ruby` in the apt repositories is version 1.8.7 which is quite old. Try `apt-get install ruby1.9.1`

If that doesn't work, I would recommend using [rvm](http://rvm.io/). Install, then simply `rvm install ruby-2.0.0` which is the latest version, then `rvm use 2.0.0`. If shoes doesn't work under any of these  versions, it's probably a bug in shoes.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I have `ruby 2.0.0p247 ` and `gem 2.0.6` now, but i still get `no such file to load -- rubygems` if i try to run shoes